# Firebase Anonymous User Authentication flow

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I have the following js code where I try to login on the blog_root object and then use my user_root to listen for any changes with user_root.on("child_added",...)

```
var root = new Firebase( /*my firebase url*/);
    var blog_root = root.child("blog");
    var user_root;
    console.log("====");
    blog_root.authAnonymously(function(err, authData) {
        if(err){
            console.log("user not authenticated?"+err);
        }else{
            console.log("user authenticated?"+authData.uid);
            if(authData){
                user_root = blog_root.child(authData.uid);
                user_root.set(authData);
            }
        }
    },{
      remember: "sessionOnly"
    });
user_root.on(
    "child_added", //event_name
    function(snapshot) {
        //called for each existing element and each new element 
    }
```

Using this code specifically my user_root object is shown to be undefined. I check my data and the anonymous user has been successfully added to the blog_root, but I cannot seem to be able to listen to changes on user_root.

What I gather is that the user_root.on("child_added") event is fired on my authentication statement, but this makes no sense to me because user_root is initialized inside the authentication statement.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

The `authAnonymously` method is asynchronous, and the callback is invoked *after* you first get to `user_root.on('child_added', ...)`. Try moving this listener into the callback from `authAnonymously`.

Also, note that each time you call `authAnonymously()`, you're creating a new session. Sessions are automatically persisted by default. To check whether or not the user is already authenticated, try `ref.getAuth()`, and only invoke `authAnonymously()` if the user is unauthenticated (`ref.getAuth() === null`).

Comment: Woot! Ok so now everything makes sense. Thanks Rob!